# How can I switch from one web page to other?

Tags: python, django, web-services

I want to create a webpage. In it there is a go_to button named `goto_button`. Whenever the user presses this button the new webpage will be called and the old one will be destroyed. To do this, I have to put a button on the web page, in the html file. However how can I switch from one web page to another?  The go_to webpage address is *www.kleol.com*

```
     if button is pressed
          go to web-page kleol // how can I do that?
```

NOTE: I am new to Django.

Comment: Maybe an `<a href="http://www.kleol.com">goto</a>` tag is enough?

Comment: @okm have put button on the webpage  `<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="login_button" style="width: 109px; "/>`. Whenever it is clicked,the web page should redirrected to X.com. X.com layout is defined with the function named as y.py. How can I redirrect web-page ?

Comment: @gcc Could you post a question to elaborate the issue? I've no idea about its context, sounds like you need some javascript or set [the action attribute of the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) to `'http://x.com/'`...

Answer (score 2):

Simple HTML tag like the following will work:

```
<a href="http://www.kleol.com">Go to Kleol</a>
```

There's nothing that is django related.It is simple html.

Comment: @okm have put button on the webpage  `<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="login_button" style="width: 109px; "/>`. Whenever it is clicked,the web page should redirrected to X.com. X.com layout is defined with the function named as y.py. How can I redirrect web-page ?